# Proper way to add an image file inside a PDF document generated with Reportlab on AppEngine Python

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, reportlab

I'm trying to generate a PDF report using reportlab on App Engine Python.

But I don't know how to attach an image properly.

The image is static.

This is the directory tree of my project.

[image]

and this is what I do (inside '**chipas.py**') to get the image:

```
im = Image('../static/logo.png',1*inch, 1*inch)
story.append(im)
...
```

The stack trace I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\Python\windows\AppEngine\google\appengine\ext\webapp_webapp25.py",
>   line 701, in **call**
>       handler.get(*groups)   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\chipas.py",
>   line 1035, in get
>       doc.build(story)   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py",
>   line 1117, in build
>       BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)   File
>   "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py",
>   line 880, in build
>       self.handle_flowable(flowables)   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py",
>   line 763, in handle_flowable
>       if frame.add(f, canv, trySplit=self.allowSplitting):   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\platypus\frames.py",
>   line 159, in _add
>       w, h = flowable.wrap(aW, h)   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\platypus\flowables.py",
>   line 408, in wrap
>       return self.drawWidth, self.drawHeight   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\platypus\flowables.py",
>   line 402, in **getattr**
>       self._setup_inner()   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\platypus\flowables.py",
>   line 368, in _setup_inner
>       img = self._img   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\platypus\flowables.py",
>   line 398, in **getattr**
>       self._img = ImageReader(self._file)   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\lib\utils.py",
>   line 541, in **init**
>       if _isPILImage(fileName):   File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Desarrollo\workspace\python\chipas-windows\src\reportlab\lib\utils.py",
>   line 521, in _isPILImage
>       return isinstance(im,Image.Image) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Image' INFO     2012-02-29 19:54:37,276
>   dev_appserver.py:4247] "GET
>   /pdf?pedido=ahVkZXZ-Y2hpcGFzLWludGhlY2xvdWRyLwsSBlBlZGlkbyIjMjAxMi0wMi0yOSAxOTo1NDoxOHRlc3RAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20M
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 -

What's the proper way to add an image file inside a pdf document generated with reportlab?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not using RML markup? There is cool free library from Zope http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.rml

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 ways this could be done.

## If you are just working with a canvas:

```
canvas.drawInlineImage(APP_ROOT + "/static/footer_image.png", inch*.25, inch*.25, PAGE_WIDTH-(.5*inch), (.316*inch))
```

## OR if you are using platypus and flowables

(answer taken from: http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/jan/28/writing-pdfs-python-adding-images/)

```
import os
import urllib2
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Image

filename = './python-logo.png'

def get_python_image():
    """ Get a python logo image for this example """
    if not os.path.exists(filename) :
        response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/community/logos/python-logo.png')
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.write(response.read())
        f.close()

get_python_image()

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("image.pdf", pagesize=letter)
parts = []
parts.append(Image(filename))
doc.build(parts)
```

Comment: thanks Francis. I already saw those examples but they don't apply to this scenario. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

ReportLab requires **PIL** for images other than JPEG (PIL is not available on Appengine production), but it does support JPEG natively (see note below).  So you need to provide ReportLab with JPEG images when rendering PDF files.  With user-submitted images, I first use Appengine's API to transform the image to JPEG before rendering.

So step 1 is to change the logo from *png* to *jpeg*.

Secondly, Appengine does not allow you to read files from the static directory.  It gives a '**File not Accessible**' error if you try. Switch the .jpg to a directory other than /static/.

So whatever method you use to define the relative path to the file (gfortune's code works perfectly for this), to render the image, just use:

```
  f = open(path_to_file, 'rb')

  story.append( Image(f) )
```

Note:  Several years ago, ReportLab had a bug where it would still try to access PIL, even for JPEG files.  I corresponded with the developers, who provided a build that bypassed PIL for JPEG files.  I'm not sure which build is the current build, so keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks John. I tried what you suggested with no success =(. 
I created a folder named 'archivos' that contains the 'jpeg' image, then I just used the code provided by gfortune to define the relative path to the file: im = open(path_relative_to_file(_file_, '../archivos/jpeg.jpeg'),'rb')  story.append(Image(im))
but I get this exception: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/home/lucas/Dropbox/Desarrollo/Python/Documentacion/AppEngine/Using GAE - Libro/workspace/chipas-inthecloud/archivos/logo.jpeg'

Comment: The first argument for path_relative_to_file() should be "_ _file_ _"(two underscores) rather than "file".  Besides that, I'm not sure what else to suggest to define the path correctly in your situation.  But the issue at this stage is hooking into the file rather than rendering it.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it with the two underscores but still can't avoid the 'File not Accessible' error =(
Thanks anyway John.

Comment: I don't know if this a proper way of accessing the file, but doing this: im = open(os.path.dirname("file(two underscores)")+'/archivos/logo.jpg','rb') story.append(Image(im)) I get this error: ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed

Comment: Looks like you are getting the file and opening it.  The error you're getting is ReportLab attempting to open PIL.  But as I mentioned in my original post, some earlier builds of ReportLab attemoted to unnecessarily load PIL for JPEG files; then later builds did not.  It might be worth downloading the trunk build from the repository to ensure you have the latest version:   https://svn.reportlab.com/svn/public/reportlab/trunk

Comment: Pil is now available for appengine. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Answer (score 3):

### Main solution

It looks like the original error for this post is due to PIL maybe not being installed or perhaps a bug in an old version of PIL.  See http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic18147.html for a similar situation.  Try installing a recent version of PIL.

Also, see [Appengine - Reportlab (Get Photo from Model)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798885/appengine-reportlab-get-photo-from-model) towards the end of the accepted solution and the comments.

### Another potential problem in the code posted

Although this may not be directly related to the question asked, are you certain that `im` loaded correctly?  Keep in mind that the path you've setup is relative to the directory from where the app was launched rather than relative to the current file.  Use `__file__` and some `os.path` trickery to make the path relative to `chipas.py` assuming that's the problem.  If it's not the problem you're dealing with right now, it's certainly one you'll run into soon.

To reference a path relative to the directory of the current file, you would use something like:

### Code

```
import os.path

def path_relative_to_file(base_file_path, relative_path):
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(base_file_path))
    return os.path.normpath(os.path.join(base_dir, relative_path))



print(__file__)
print(path_relative_to_file(__file__, '../static/logo.png'))


#Breaks if this code is run from a different directory
print(os.path.abspath('../static/logo.png'))
```

### Output

```
gfortune@gfortune:/var/log$ python /home/gfortune/temp/temp.py
/home/gfortune/temp/temp.py
/home/gfortune/static/logo.png
/var/static/logo.png
```

Note that the path to '../static' works even though I launched the program from /var/log.  Also note that blindly using ../static with abspath breaks if you run it from /var/log.

You can use that function as a little helper function by passing it `__file__` from the module in question or you can just use the logic from it directly in `chipas.py`

Comment: gfortune, could you provide an example of how to do that? Many thanks

Comment: Certainly, I'll update the answer.  Did you check `im` to see if it loaded properly?

Comment: gfortune, I do logging.info(im) and it prints: <reportlab.platypus.flowables.Image instance at 0x042CFC88>

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunate.  I took a look at the reportlab code and the Image class doesn't give you any decent way to tell if it's going to load properly or fail.  Something isn't matching up in your code either. Please update the original post with the full Traceback and a larger chunk of your application code (especially related to `Image`)

Comment: thanks for helping gfortune... I posted the full stacktrace and I can post the whole method if you want, but those are all the lines of code related to Image.

Comment: Thanks, the traceback ended up being critical.  The exception is not triggered inside your code.  See updated answer.

Comment: thanks gfortune. I'll try re-installing PIL. Although it seems that could be something regarding the relative path
because when I test examples that work with images, they run normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple function: 
This Worked For me....

```
def PrintImage(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response,topMargin=2)

    doc.pagesize = landscape(A6)
    elements = []
    I = Image('http://demoschoolzen.educationzen.com/images/tia.png')
    I.drawHeight =  0.7*inch
    I.drawWidth = 0.7*inch
    elements.append(I)
    doc.build(elements) 
    return response
```

and Call it from your URLs

Comment: How does one call the function above from the URL?  Can't find a suitable example.  I'm using Django.