# Issue writing temp images to temp pdf in pyramid with reportlabs

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, pyramid, reportlab

I am using python 3, with pyramid and reportlabs to generate dynamic pdfs.

I am having a issue writing images in to a pdf. I am using Reportlab in a web to generate a pdf with images, by my images are not stored locally, they are on a remote server. I am downloading them locally into a temp directory ( they are saving, I have checked) When i go to add the images to the pdf, they space is allocating but image is not showing up.

Here is my relevant code (simplified):

```
      # creates pdf in memory
      doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdfName, pagesize=A4)

      elements = []

      for item in model['items']:
        # image goes here:
        if item['IMAGENAME']:
          response = getImageFromRemoteServer(item['IMAGENAME'])
          dir_filename = directory + item['IMAGENAME']
          if response.status_code == 200:
          with open(dir_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content():
              f.write(chunk)

        questions.append(Image(dir_filename, width=2*inch, height=2*inch))

      # create and save the pdf
      doc.build(elements,canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas)
```

I have followed the user guide here https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf and have tried the above way, plus embedded images (as the user guide says in the paragraph section) and putting the image in the table.

I also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505098/proper-way-to-add-an-image-file-inside-a-pdf-document-generated-with-reportlab-o): and it did not help me.

My question is really, what is the right what to download an image and put in a pdf?

EDIT: fixed code indentation

EDIT 2:

Answered, I was finally about to get the images in the PDF. I am not sure what was the trigger to get it to work. The only thing that know I change was now I am using urllib to do the request and before i was not. Here is the my working code (simplified for the question only, this is more abstracted and encapsulated in my code.):

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdfName, pagesize=A4)
# array of elements in the pdf
elements = []
for question in model['questions']:
  # image goes here:
  if question['IMAGEFILE']:
    filename = question['IMAGEFILE']
    dir_filename = directory + filename
    url = get_url(settings, filename)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    raw_data = response.read()      

    f = open(dir_filename, 'wb')
    f.write(raw_data)
    f.close()

    response.close()
    myImage = Image(dir_filename)
    myImage.drawHeight = 2* inch
    myImage.drawWidth = 2* inch
    myImage.hAlign = "LEFT"
    elements.append(myImage)

# create and save the pdf
doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: I've added `reportlab` tag.

Comment: What image format? You need PIL installed if the image format is not .jpeg.

Comment: GIF, PNG and JPG. and yes i have PIL installed.

Comment: Please fix indentation of code sample starting from line 6

Answer (score 0):

Make your code independent from where the files come from. Separate file/resource retrieval from document generation. Ensure that your toolset is working with local files. Encapsulate the code to load files in a loader class or function. The encapsulation is what matters. Noticed this again this week while looking at [thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor) loader classes.
If that works, you know reportlab, PIL and your application basically work.

Then make your code work with remote files using URI like `http://path/to/remote/files`.

Afterwards you can switch from using your fileloader or your httploader depending on environment or use case.

Another option to go would be to make your code work with local files using URI like `file://path/to/file`

This way the only thing that changes when switching from local to remote is the URL. Probably you need a python library supporting this. [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) library is well suited for downloading things, most probably it supports URL scheme `file://`  as well.

Comment: Yes, i know about code encapsulation, This was just code snippet of code before cleaning and refactoring. Thank you for advice and insight, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I did not meant to emphasize encapsulation. You asked a question regarding two tasks and I proposed to split things up to reduce complexity. BTW - a pip freeze could be interesting to see your python environment if someone wants to reproduce it.

Comment: Here is a link a my pip freeze https://gist.github.com/mdewey/af3904a76120cd6f6620

Comment: Also, I took your advice and broke it down. I can create the pdf with the remote image when not working in a temp directory. So that leads me to believe that there might be a race condition on when the pdf is rendered vs the directory getting cleaned up. But I am still looking into it.

Comment: Do not hesitate to extend your code samples. The current one lacks details about temporary file implementation details and details about the context where you trigger PDF rendering. Paste it all, my mouse has a scroll wheel.

Comment: I am not sure what it was but I got the code working.I broke it down and as I re-assembled it, it started working. I will update the OP with the working code.

Comment: Both code samples you provided are more or less useless for debugging. No imports, some unknown and unused variables. Please stop changing and truncating your code within questions at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the `lazy` parameter was responsible that your first code sample did not render the images. Triggering reportlab PDF rendering outside of the context managers for temporary files could have lead to this behaviour.

`reportlab.platypus.flowables.py` (using version 3.1.8)

```
class Image(Flowable):
    """an image (digital picture).  Formats supported by PIL/Java 1.4 (the Python/Java Imaging Library
       are supported.  At the present time images as flowables are always centered horozontally
       in the frame. We allow for two kinds of lazyness to allow for many images in a document
       which could lead to file handle starvation.
       lazy=1 don't open image until required.
       lazy=2 open image when required then shut it.
    """
    _fixedWidth = 1
    _fixedHeight = 1
    def __init__(self, filename, width=None, height=None, kind='direct', mask="auto", lazy=1):
    """If size to draw at not specified, get it from the image."""
    self.hAlign = 'CENTER'
    self._mask = mask
    fp = hasattr(filename,'read')
    if fp:
        self._file = filename
        self.filename = repr(filename)
        ...
```

The last three lines of the code example tell you that you can pass an object that has a `read` method. This is exactly what a call to `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` returns. Using that memory buffer you create an instance of Image. No need to have write access to filesystem, no need to delete these files after PDF rendering. Applying our new knowledge to improve code readability. Since your use-case includes retrieval of remote resources using memory buffers that support python file API could be a much cleaner approach to assemble your PDF files.

```
from contextlib import closing
import urllib.request

doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdfName, pagesize=A4)
# array of elements in the pdf
elements = []
for question in model['questions']:
  # download image and create Image from file-like object
  if question['IMAGEFILE']:
    filename = question['IMAGEFILE']
    image_url = get_url(settings, filename)

    with closing(urllib.request.urlopen(image_url)) as image_file:
      myImage = Image(image_file, width=2*inch, height=2*inch)
      myImage.hAlign = "LEFT"
      elements.append(myImage)

# create and save the pdf
doc.build(elements)
```

References

- [Coding with context managers](http://python3porting.com/improving.html#coding-with-context-managers)